# How to connect multiple computers to the same PostgreSQL database?

Tags: java, windows, postgresql

I am working in an application that connect to a PostgreSQL Database and will allow to access from differents computers connected in the same local network.

It's already working, but when it is used in more than one computer at the same time, the server disconnect the current computer to attend to a new connection.

There's some way to make that the PostgreSQL server attend to more than one computer at time?

I think that maybe, I'm doing something wrong in the way that I'm using the server.

When the application start I set the pgdata and pgport variables and check the server status with `pg_isready`, if it has no answer, I use `pg_ctl start`.

I'm using the 3389 port.

EDIT:

My problem was a logic error in the application, it was trying to open a new server with each connection instead of use the one that was already running.

Comment: How many max connections did you specify in the configuration?: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: I didn' change the default. max_connections = 100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configuration file 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\Y.X\data\postgresql.conf' has a parameter called *max_connections*, which controls the maximun numbers of connections allowed to your DB. Change it and you can allow more connections after restarting postgres.

Comment: I didn't change the default value.
max_connections = 100